# How do you fix rounding issues?

Tags: rounding

Annoying issue about rounding. I think community knows it. When you use price including tax, discounts and so on you will get 0.01 price difference. I found a solution to rewrite core class with method `round($price, 4)` and thought it might help. It was working fine, but now I faced with it again. I have a condition for export  `base_total_invoiced == base_grand_total` and this prices are `112.9230 != 112.9200` I can round them also. But it's a dirty fix.

Does anybody know good solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct fix to solve your problem, but this should be solved in the CE 1.8 release that is expexted at the end of this month,

From http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes:

**Rounding Error Fixes**

The following issues relate to one-cent rounding errors in the web store or shopping cart:

- Calculating taxes for bundled products with tiered pricing.
- Calculating the price before customization for bundled products.
- Calculating the grand total of items added to a cart in a different order.
- Viewing an order when taxes are calculated after a discount    using either row-based or unit price. Applying a discount to an order    with a shipping address different than the billing address.
- Calculating the grand total based on the order in which products are    added to the shopping cart. Specifying that prices display in the web    store excluding tax and setting a 20% tax rate (or discount rate) now    calculates the grand total correctly. It is now possible to have    grand totals in amounts like 6.99, 9.99, or 99.99—regardless of the    currency units used in the web store.
- Adding multiple items to a cart    does not affect the accuracy with which taxation is calculated.
- Subtotal (Incl. Tax) is now correct when catalog and shipping prices    include tax. Both tax and discounts are applied after tax.
- Prices    displayed in the cart and on the catalog page are consistent and    correct when catalog prices include tax, and when items in the    catalog are set to display both including and excluding tax. (In the    Admin Panel, click System > Configuration > SALES > Tax. In the right    pane, expand Calculation Settings.)
- Error in calculating the Grand    Total Excl. Tax was resolved. This error occurred in a specific    configuration: tax is applied to FPT, FPT is included in the    subtotal, and the customer selects non-taxable flat rate shipping.